# How can I fix this RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout

I'd like to see the following layout work:

```
--------------------------
| -----------            |
| |TextView1|            |
| -----------            |
| ---------------------- |
| |EditText1           | |
| ---------------------- |
| -----------            |
| |TextView2|            |
| -----------            |
| ---------------------- |
| |EditText2           | |
| ---------------------- |
| -----------            |
| |TextView3|            |
| -----------            |
| ---------------------- |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |      ImageView     | |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |--------------------| |
|   --------- --------   |
|   |Button1||Button2|   |
|   --------- --------   |
| ---------------------| |
| |     ButtonBar      | |
| ---------------------- |
|------------------------|
```

My issue: I can't make Button1 and Button2 work in this layout. They either go below the ImageView, hidden behind the ButtonBar or they get shrunk to nothing between the bottom of the ImageView and the top of the ButtonBar.

The current XML-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPostUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPostUser"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textPostUser"
        android:hint="user"
        android:maxLength="40" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPostComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editPostUser"
        android:text="comment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPostComment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textPostComment"
        android:hint="comment"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:maxLines="3" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPostCharacterCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editPostComment"
        android:text="characters"
        android:textSize="5pt" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePostResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textPostCharacterCount"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPostRotateLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagePostResult"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPostRotateRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagePostResult"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonPostRotateLeft"
        android:text="right" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPostSave"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="save" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I make the left/right buttons appear below the imageview and above the buttonbar?
I'd like to at least keep the fill_parent in both height/width of the ImageView as it scales pretty nicely on different resolutions.

Comment: +1 Just for the nice formatting that you did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImageView is set to fill_parent so there is no space left for the buttons below. You can switch the buttons and the imageview so the imageview takes all the space left when the buttons are already included:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPostRotateLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPostRotateRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonPostRotateLeft"
        android:text="right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePostResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonPostRotateLeft"
        android:layout_below="@id/textPostCharacterCount"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />
```

Comment: That was PERFECT! Accepted answer, and I also learned something along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not putting the two buttons inside a horizontal LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are set to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, as well as the linear layout. The latter will hide the former since it comes last in the xml code.

Try putting your buttons in a linear layout and align it above the footer `android:layout_above="@+id/footer"`